# Vue2: Page Is Not Rendered

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, vuejs2

Getting started with Vue 2 and nothing renders via `vue-router`. I do not receive any errors in the console, so I think I'm missing something very basic. (*The app component is just the standard one that ships with the installation, so it should be fine.*)

---

**main.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import vuex from 'vuex';
import axios from 'axios';
import routes from './routes';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';

Vue.use(vuex);
Vue.use(axios);
Vue.use(VueRouter);

let router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  scrollBehavior: (to, from, savedPosition) => savedPosition || { x: 0, y: 0 },
  routes
});

new Vue({ router }).$mount('#app');
```

**routes.js**

```
import App from './App';

let routes = [
  { path: '', component: App },
  { path: '/', component: App }
];

export default routes;
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <!-- built files will be auto injected -->
  </body>
</html>
```

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <img src="./assets/logo.png">
    <hello></hello>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Hello from './components/Hello';

export default {
  name: 'app',
  components: {
    Hello
  }
};
</script>
```

---

**Version**

`vue: 2.1.0`
`vue-router 2.1.1`

Comment: Could you also post the code for your `HTML` so we can see how you are using your router?

Comment: I haven't really messed with the `HTML` yet, but I updated the post with the relevant bits.

Comment: how can you specify more routes in your App.vue? I basically want to use App.vue as a site layout but there are no good examples.

Comment: Ask this as a separate question so that I can show you how I handled it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The `index.html` is missing `<router-view></router-view>`.

Comment: I just get an empty page.